# Ubuntu Error: Destination fle is read only

Tags: partitioning, read-only

I have recently shifted from windows to ubuntu and when i tried saving files in the hdd it shows the error that the destination is read only. I am assuming that the partition was not done properly, so is there any other way to resolve this issue than redoing the partition.Please do help.

Comment: It could also be that your partition is mounted as _read-only_. Check `fstab` to rule this out.

Comment: Where are you trying  to save files? In the directory tree of your home directory `/home/your-user-name` you should have write access (so in your Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Music, Pictures, Video ... you should be able to write). Are you trying to write into a second HDD? In that case, what file system is there?